# MOKutil: Enroll key of already installed driver

Tags: drivers, secure-boot

I installed the proprietary NVIDIA drivers on my PC using the option my distribution (Zorin OS) gave me upon first installation. Unfortunately, the signature of the driver was not enrolled to MOK, which lead to Secure Boot stopping it from loading.

Running `modinfo nvidia` tells me that the drivers are indeed signed, yet `mokutil --list-enrolled` doesn't show the signature of the driver anywhere. So it hasn't been enrolled.

How can I enroll the driver signature to MOK afterwards? I only found solutions about signing a module yourself, then enrolling your own signature to MOK - but I already have it signed, I just can't find a way to get the signature from `modinfo` into MOK.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you not import the key manually? If not, then just setup your own signing key, import, then resign the module with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't enroll a specific *signature*; you enroll the (public part of the) *key you use to make the signatures*. Usually (= unless you take over the control of the entire Secure Boot key hierarchy on your system), that key is called the Machine Owner's Key, or MOK for short.

Since Zorin is based on Ubuntu, which is in turn based on Debian, I'd expect that the standard location for the MOK signing key will be the same as in Debian, i.e. the directory `/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/`.

That directory should contain two files: `MOK.der` is the *public key* that can be used to *check* the validity of the signatures, and a corresponding `MOK.priv`, the *private key* that can be used to *create* signatures.

To restart the MOK enrollment procedure with an existing key (with which your NVidia modules are already signed), run:

```
sudo mokutil --import /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
```

It will ask you to set a one-time password for the completion of the enrolling procedure, which will happen during the next reboot.

Once you reboot the system, the Secure Boot shim will start a MOK Manager EFI utility (`/boot/efi/EFI/<distribution>/mmx64.efi`) which will ask for the password you just set, and a final confirmation that you really wish to enroll the MOK. This procedure ensures that you can only enroll the MOK if you both have root privileges and can access the physical system console.

Comment: It worked just like a charm! Thanks so much for the detailed answer. Now, I understand Secure Boot way better than before.